# ListView.builder with Wrap widget duplicates data

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list which contains days. I displayed this list of days using Wrap widget in a ListView.builder, the data displays but it duplicates...

How can I remove the duplications?

```
 ListView.builder(
                    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: days == null ? 0 : days.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Wrap(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          ...days.map((date) {
                            return Container(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.4,
                              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              child: ListTile(
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/logEntry');
                                },
                                title: const DefaultText(
                                  size: 18,
                                  text: "Day 1",
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                  weight: FontWeight.w500,
                                ),
                                subtitle: DefaultText(
                                  size: 15,
                                  text: "${date.day}/${date.month}/${date.year}"
                                      .toString(),
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                  weight: FontWeight.w500,
                                ),
                                trailing: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                              ),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `ListView.builder` like with wrap like this. You can shift to `ListView` just to handle height-overflow.

```dart
ListView(
  children: [
    Wrap(),
  ],
),
```

Comment: If I want to get the index of each data... How can I do this?

Comment: try like `Wrap( children:  List.generate( days?.length??0, (index) { return Container(..`

Comment: I'm getting the error "The element type 'List<Container>' can't be assigned to the list type 'widget'."

Comment: like `Wrap(children: List.generate(data?.length ?? 0, (index) => Container(..)))` ? what is `data` on your case

Comment: Data is a list of DateTime

Comment: Does top comment working ?

Comment: Glad to help, you may like to check returning Row from ItemBuilder